# JUnit: How to bundle @Test methods to a suite?

Tags: eclipse, junit, junit4

I have several classes each containing several methods annotated with `@Test`. The classes are **not** extending `TestCase`. Now I want to

- write a main that executes all these methods (for command line use)
- create a class that can be "Run as -> JUnit Test" in Eclipse executing all these methods

Since the classes are no `TestCase`s I can't just add them to a suite. Also extending `TestCase` is not an option because the test methods are just annotated and their names don't start with 'test'.

How can I do this?

Comment: For the first, you'll have to call each of them manually. For the second, why would you need to do that? Eclipse can run all of your test cases even if they are in separate classes.

Comment: I didn't find this option... How can you tell Eclipse to run them all?

Comment: You can set up run configurations for a project. Right click on your project. Then selecte 'Run as' -> 'Run configurations'. Within that you can select run all tests.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this feature, especially since I didn't notice that the selection of the methods can be restricted to a certain package / directory. That helps a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Guess I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up run configurations for a project. Right click on your project. Then selecte 'Run as' -> 'Run configurations'. Within that you can select run all tests

Comment: Since this feature wasn't used in the end, I didn't look further into this. However, your answer was the most helpful to get my task done, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
  Test1.class,
  Test2.class,
  Test3.class,
  Test4.class
})
public class YourTestSuite {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What Eugene posted works if you have a small number of classes.  If you want all the tests in a certain package pattern, [Classpath Suite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) lets you specify this with patterns instead of listing them all out.